# Schemes associated to algebraic cycles and local complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

We know that for an effective divisor on a smooth projective variety there is a natural way of associating to it a scheme, in particular using the Cartier divisor. Can we do the same for higher codimension effective algebraic cycles? More precisely, let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $Z_c:=\sum_i a_iZ_i$ be an algebraic cycle on $X$, where $Z_i$ are integral of the same codimension and $a_i>0$. Then,

1) Is there a natural way of associating to $Z_c$ a scheme $Z$ such that the corresponding segre class $s(Z,X)$ (notation as in Fulton's Intersection theory, chapter $4$) is the cycle $Z_c$?

2) Furthermore, if $Z_{c_{\mathrm{red}}}=\sum_i Z_i$ is local complete intersection subscheme in $X$, then can we find such a $Z$ which is also local complete intersection subscheme in $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, let $X$ be a plane and $Z_i$ a point, then if $Z_c = 2 Z_i$, then the scehme would have to be a length $2$ subcheme supported at the point. But there are a $\mathbb P^1$ of these (the schemes defined by the ideal $(x^2,xy,y^2,ax+by)$) and there is no natural choice.

2) Locally, yes, by taking the $a_i$th power of one of the defining equations. I'm not sure if this sort of local existence can be glued globally - because of the non-naturalness mentioned earlier, this is not clear.